# How to set UTF-8 encoding content type in JSP pages using FreeMarker

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, utf-8, freemarker

I want to set `UTF-8` encoding in my `Spring MVC` web application I'm using `netbeans 8 ide` and I changed the config options to set all the pages to `UTF-8`, I confirmed this by clicking help->about and checked the system parameters it says `UTF-8`, but when I check properties by clicking a file it says `ISO-8859-1`.

So I run my app and I checked the content type in firefox, and it says
`Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`, so it appears that even if the properties window that appears when I click a file says `ISO-8859-1`, the browser takes it as a `UTF-8` because I changed the default file encoding in nebeans to UTF-8.

I also put in my head tag this `<meta charset="UTF-8">` since I'm using html5  but I saved the files as a `.JSP`

The file doesn't have any JSP code but I saved with this extension because there was already too many pages like this in the project I didn't bother to change them.

This are my methods in my config class I'm using java configuration

```
 @Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return freeMarkerConfigurer;
}

@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver() {

    FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    viewResolver.setCache(false);   //Set to true during production
    //        viewResolver.setOrder(0);

    return viewResolver;
}
```

and this line is in my pom .xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

1) All my pages have the  `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

2) I change the default encoding in netbeans to utf-8,

3) my view resolver methods have utf-8 options

4) This appears in my browser `Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`

Why is the utf-8 encoding not working I'm missing something? the only way to make it work is if I put this line at the top of my pages `<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` but since I'm not using jsp that string tag appears in the view.

Can the problem be that when I click the properties option inside netbeans ide  the page says `ISO-8859-1`, but this happens after I copy and paste boilerplate html code, before when the file is created is created as UTF-8 but I'm copying HTML5 code I don't know why it changes to ``ISO-8859-1`, but I think that this doesn't matter since in the browser it says`Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: JSP pages using FreeMarker. What?

Comment: is just the extension but all the content is html5 the only thing that I think is jsp is this freemarker directive `<#assign security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] />` for spring security tag libs

Comment: ""_only thing that I think is jsp is this freemarker directive_". Again: what?

Comment: I need that JspTagLibs for spring security

Comment: That has nothing to do with JSP. I don't understand why your freemarker templates have a JSP extension, or why JSP is in the question at all - but something tells me this is the crux of the issue.

Comment: I'm going to change the resolver extension to .ftl or .html and see if it fix the problem, is there a way to fix this without chanign the extension

Comment: Exactly what problem does this encoding issue cause?